# In some page, type 5 + 15 in chrome devtool console, the output is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Rt, in `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/domchristie/humps/master/humps.js`, I type 5 + 15 in chrome devTool's Console pane, the output is undefined, I think the output should be 20 (In other web page, for example https://google.com, it is 20)

[Figure 1 the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnhWd.png)

And I notice that this page use CSP (Content-Security-Policy) with http header's `Content-Security-Policy` is "default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox"

I think the key maybe `sandbox`, but I change other page's http header with CSP with sandbox, it

Comment: It's a bug in devtools, https://crbug.com/1104503.

Comment: @wOxxOm get it, thank you very much!